# How to check the type?

Tags: types, ml, typechecking

Say I have the following datatype declared:

```
datatype 'a data = Zero | One of 'a | Many of 'a list;
```

I need a function that checks what type it received. For example if foo receives a Zero or a Many with zero 'a then it will return Zero. And I just can't figure out how to do that(I'm extremely new to ML). Here's what I got so far:

```
fun foo(Zero) = Zero    
    | foo(Many []) = Zero;
```

foo is suppose to be: 'a data -> 'a data. Btw.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. The code you wrote should compile and work, but it misses some other possible cases. If you called `foo` with `One 4` or `Many [1,2,3]` it would fail with a `Match` exception, since the definition of `foo` doesn't cover these cases.

Here's what you'd need to start with to cover them:

```
fun foo(Zero) = Zero    
  | foo(Many []) = Zero
  | foo(Many xs) = (* xs bound to the non-empty list of 'a *)
  | foo(One x) = (* x bound to a single 'a *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
Do you have any suggestions to how to make it to return an object of One if it receives Many with only one 'a? Some sort of casting is needed I suppose.

Comment: You definitely don't need casting for that. Just add another clause with the pattern `Many [x]` which will match when the function is called with a singleton list. (just as `[]` matches the empty list, `[x]` match the singleton list and `[x,y]` matches a two element list, etc)

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I ended up doing!